# Error 123: os.remove on files with special characters

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am trying to delete some folders with rmtree() in Python on Windows. The Command fails with following error:

```
File "C:\Miniconda\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Miniconda\lib\shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info()) 
File "C:\Miniconda\lib\shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree os.remove(fullname)

WindowsError: [Error 123] Die Syntax f³r den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentrõgerbezeichnung ist falsch: 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpsh6uwz\\uClibc-.9.32\\test\\API\\pthread-RPP?TPP.SUSv4.syms'
Exception WindowsError: WindowsError(123, 'Die Syntax f\xfcr den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentr\xe4gerbezeichnung ist falsch') in <bound method TempDir.__del__ of <tempdir.TempDir object at 0x0000000014B301D0>> ignored
```

The Error basically says, that the filename contains Special Characters which are not allowed under Windows. That is true.

How can I delete these files anyway?

Comment: pass Unicode filenames and see if it helps. What is your Python version?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, the version of Python is older than 3.3 if it reports a `WindowsError`, so it's probably Python 2.7. That means you're probably right. Listing the directory using byte strings resulted in an ANSI conversion that replaced an unmapped Unicode character with "?". The only sane option on Windows is to ensure all filepaths are Unicode because the filesystem encoding is Unicode.

Comment: @eryksun please, do not call Unicode "encoding". In Python: `unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)`. Unicode is not a character encoding (how Unicode strings are represented internally doesn't matter for the definition)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, the filesystem is UTF-16LE -- a system of numeric codes that represent characters.

Comment: @eryksun : again, the API is Unicode: it doesn't matter how it is implemented (for the purpose of the definition): Unicode is not an encoding (whatever some Windows editors might say), don't call it that.

Comment: Thanks. Youre right. Passing Unicode filename helped. I updated and adjusted code to Python 3.5 and this also seems to solve the problem. Do you by chance know why? Does 3.5 handle strings different?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I think we're just talking past each other. There are two common meanings for the word "encoding".  In my first statement I was thinking of an encoding like `u'\x65\x6e\x63\x6f\x64\x69\x6e\x67'`, i.e. a conversion of text into a sequence of codes. Two sides have to agree on how to interpret these numbers (what character it is, and the associated glyph). In the second statement I switched gears to the second meaning, for the UTF format (i.e. how the code is represented as bytes), hoping that would be less of a problem.

Comment: @FerrisGarden, string literals in Python 3 are Unicode, so the string ultimately passed to `os.listdir` is Unicode. This returns a Unicode file listing (from the WinAPI Unicode APIs `FindFirstFileW`  and `FindNextFileW`), which is used to delete the files and directories using the Unicode APIs `DeleteFileW` and `RemoveDirectoryW`. Everything stays Unicode, which avoids a lossy translation to and from the system's ANSI codepage. In Python 2 you have to be careful to start with a `u''` prefixed Unicode literal.

Answer (score 0):

So just to summarize these comments / solutions in a single line for other readers like me:

```
shutil.rmtree(unicode(path))
```

Solves the issue.